# Yarn - How do I update specific dependencies in package.json?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

Recently I updated nextjs to `"next": "^13.5.6",`, which [broke storybook](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/24234). This was subsequently fixed and therefore the solution is to also upgrade all storybook related packages.

not working

```
    "@storybook/nextjs ": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/react ": "^7.4.0",
    ...
```

fixed

```
    "@storybook/nextjs ": "^7.6.17",
    "@storybook/react ": "^7.6.17",
    ...
```

The problem is, however, that while the current ranges in package.json satisfy the new updated version in `yarn.lock`, it **does not** convey the message that `7.4.0` is in fact NOT supported minimum version.

##### How can I update the packages to latest matching version, while also having that reflected in package.json as the new minimum?

BTW: I am using workspaces and these are the packages that need upgrading

```
yarn workspace holograph-storybook upgrade @storybook/addon-essentials @storybook/addon-interactions @storybook/addon-links @storybook/addon-onboarding @storybook/addon-styling @storybook/blocks @storybook/nextjs @storybook/react @storybook/testing-library storybook storybook-dark-mode
```